# Netlogo : creating a list from others lists and adding calculation : is it the "best" way?

Tags: list, netlogo, nested-lists

I wrote down those lines in order to calculate for each patch a `change-LU-list` that is used to randomly chose one of the LU (item 0 item i of change-LU-list) from the associated weight (using the final function `rnd:weighted-one-of-list`.

As you can see, I'm using data that are lists of lists to build the `change-LU-list`, then I work some calculation from the updated items, remove the unwanted items so I finally only have the `LU` its weight.

Is it the best way to do that in netlogo ? **Or should I use the `array` extension ?**

As the `change-LU-list` is different for each patch, I set it back to nul values inside the `ask patches` block. **Or should I use a local variable for `change-LU-list` ?**

**I also have an issue with `remove-item´ command** which is not working as expected, an error request "a command".

I'm still in the learning process and **looking for any advice to build my model in the netlogo-style.**

Thanks for your time ! (sorry if it is too hard to read, I could edit to make it look simplier if necessary)

```
to change-LU

  
  ask patches with [eligible = true] [
  ;; creation of a list of possible LU (from historic data item 1) and adding a second item for the weight, it should be updated for every patch !
  set change-LU-list map [inner-list -> (list item 1 inner-list 0 0 0 ) ] historic-data
  ;; let's replace item 1 by the area, item 2 by the yield, item 3 by the price, item 4 by the cost, item 5 by the historic, item 6 by the final weight
  let i 0
  while [i < length historic-data] [
  let x item 0 item i historic-data
  
  set change-LU-list replace-item i change-LU-list (replace-item 1 item i change-LU-list (area))      ;; area is a patch variable
 
  set change-LU-list replace-item i change-LU-list (replace-item 2 item i change-LU-list (last (first (filter [yield-inner-list -> (item 0 yield-inner-list = year) ;; year is a global variable
      AND (abs (real-x - item 1 yield-inner-list) <= 0.01375)
      AND (abs (real-y - item 2 yield-inner-list) <= 0.01375)
      AND (item 3 yield-inner-list = x ) ] yield-data))))
          
  set change-LU-list replace-item i change-LU-list (replace-item 3 item i change-LU-list ( item 2 (first (filter [sgm-inner-list -> (item 0 sgm-inner-list = year) AND (item 1 sgm-inner-list = x )] sgm-data))))
  set change-LU-list replace-item i change-LU-list (replace-item 4 item i change-LU-list ( item 3 (first (filter [sgm-inner-list -> (item 0 sgm-inner-list = year) AND (item 1 sgm-inner-list = x )] sgm-data))))
  
  set change-LU-list replace-item i change-LU-list (replace-item 5 item i change-LU-list ( item 3 (first(filter [historic-inner-list -> (item 0 historic-inner-list = LU) AND (item 1 historic-inner-list = x) ] historic-data))))
      
  set change-LU-list replace-item i change-LU-list (replace-item 6 item i change-LU-list ( (( (item 2 item i change-LU-list) * (item 3 item i change-LU-list)) / (item 4 item i change-LU-list)) * (item 5 item i change-LU-list)))
  
      
  set change-LU-list remove-item i change-LU-list (remove-item 2 item 0 change-LU-list)
  set change-LU-list remove-item i change-LU-list (remove-item 3 item 0 change-LU-list)
  set change-LU-list remove-item i change-LU-list (remove-item 4 item 0 change-LU-list)
  set change-LU-list remove-item i change-LU-list (remove-item 5 item 0 change-LU-list)    
      ]
  let LU-result first rnd:weighted-one-of-list change-LU-list last
  set LU LU-result ;; updating the patch properties "LU"
    ] 
end
```

Comment: I think the question you are asking is about ten times too complicated to get a reply. It's not clear by inspection what you are doing or why you are doing it, or what, for that matter an LU is.   Can you reduce your question to something like "I have a list of lists that I need to iterate through.  What's the best way to do that?"

Comment: Or maybe order your list so that a "foreach" command will iterate it the direction you need to ( assuming that always goes in list order, which I haven't confirmed "   A foreach ... foreach ...  nesting is pretty clean and obvious to the reader, if that can do the operations you need done.

Comment: See the dictionary.  Foreach can run an anonymous block.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the best way to do that in netlogo ? Or should I use the array
> extension ?

For sure you do not want to be changing a large list many times.
But it is incredibly inefficient to build a huge list then reduce it.
If I understand the problem,  each row ( i ) is independent of each other row, so I'd suggest computing the two values you need ( a number and a weight ) for each "i", and storing that result in an array, since you know how big the array will be.   Skip making any huge list. But within each "i" lists are probably as easy to work with as arrays.

> As the change-LU-list is different for each patch, I set it back to
> nul values inside the ask patches block. Or should I use a local
> variable for change-LU-list ?

You definitely do not want the memory requirements of a huge list times the number of patches. Don't use local variables.

> I also have an issue with `remove-item´ command which is not working
> as expected, an error request "a command".

You have a command that doesn't make sense to me. Check the
Dictionary for syntax.

remove-item only has two parameters, an item number and a list.
I don't know what your third item in parenthesis is doing.

Wade
( "available for hire, see profile" )

Comment: Hi Wade, thank you for taking the time to read and comment my question. As per the Netlogo dictionnary, the `remove-item` command should be used just like the `replace-item` command and this is what I did but it doesn't seem to work the same way for nested lists (which is what is in parenthesis).

Comment: So your advice would be : rather than building lists of list with data (coming from other lists), I should just compute right away the weight (item 6 of each nested lists) ? Since the data to compute the item 6 are coming from other lists, where I need to use a filter command to extract them, ... at first sight, that would lead to huge and messy command...

Comment: sarah, the total data structure you are building is much clearer to you than to me, but I think I'm simply saying to process it horizontally instead of vertically.  Definitely don't keep modifying a huge list of lists, as each change requires rewriting the entire thing in memory.  It's the SAME calculations,  just in a different order.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice Wade, I'll will rethink it more horizontally. Will update the post when its done ;-)